# What is the behavior of isReadOnly JDBC parameter while using PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

The Java JDBC Connection class allows setting a parameter called readOnly, but what is it used for?

According to [JDBC documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html):

> readOnly is used to put the connection in read-only mode

According to [HikariCP documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP):

> This property controls whether Connections obtained from the pool are
>   in read-only mode by default. Note some databases do not support the
>   concept of read-only mode, while others provide query optimizations
>   when the Connection is set to read-only. Whether you need this
>   property or not will depend largely on your application and database.
>   Default: false

But what is a connection in read-only mode? What is the concept? A connection that allows SELECT statements only?

Does a read-only connection provide any benefits with PostgreSQL JDBC driver?

Comment: You can turn on read-only mode if you want to prevent any accidental changes to the database. I don't think it has any performance advantages in Postgres (it might have in other databases)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can browse PostgreSQL JDBC driver on [github](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc). Implementation of [Connection.setReadOnly](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgConnection.java#L761) indicates that when you're calling that method, one of the following SQL statements sent to the database:

```
SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY
```

or

```
SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ WRITE
```

Now if we will read [PostgreSQL reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-transaction.html), it specifies:

> The transaction access mode determines whether the transaction is read/write or read-only. Read/write is the default. When a transaction is read-only, the following SQL commands are disallowed: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and COPY FROM if the table they would write to is not a temporary table; all CREATE, ALTER, and DROP commands; COMMENT, GRANT, REVOKE, TRUNCATE; and EXPLAIN ANALYZE and EXECUTE if the command they would execute is among those listed. This is a high-level notion of read-only that does not prevent all writes to disk.

So basically the main benefit is that you won't be able to accidentally modify data. It's similar to using `Collections.unmodifiableList` and generally will lead to a more robust code, so if you're sure that a given transaction is expected to be read-only, use that property.